# Attempt to get items to display and hide is failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have different sets of data that I want to show when someone would click on the button for the info they want to see. One part of this is working right now, which is I want the first block of information to show upon page load. However, whenever I click on the other buttons, the info container goes away and it doesn't show anything. I do not have any errors displaying in my console and I don't see what it is that I am doing wrong.

Does anyone see anything that I am overlooking?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('.big-three-names').click(function() {
         var i = $( this ).html();
         $('.big-three-info').css("display", "none")
         $('.big-three-info').eq(i-1).css("display", "block");
     });

     $('.big-three-info').eq(0).css("display", "block");
});
```

```css
.big-three-out {
 background-color: #CCC;
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto 0;
/* padding: 15px 0;*/
}
.big-three {
 margin: 75px 7.5% 25px 7.5%;
 height: 900px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
#big-three-title {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.6em;
 padding: 50px 0 30px 0;
}
#big-three-description {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.3em;
}
#big-three-names-out {
 width: 100%;
 height: 75px;
 margin: 50px 0;
}
.big-three-names {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 2px solid #FFF;
 width: 33.05%;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #000;
 color: #FFF;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.big-three-names:hover {
 background-color: blue;
 color: #FFF;
}
.big-three-info {
 margin: 50px 20%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 height: 550px;
  display: none; 
}
#big-three-info-title { 
 width: 100%;
 margin: 100px 0 25px 50px;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
#big-three-info-description { 
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: 50px;
 font-size: 1em;
}
.show{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="big-three-out">
    <div class="big-three">
        <div id="big-three-title">The Big three</div>
        <div id="big-three-description">Description.</div>
        <div id="big-three-names-out">
            <div class="big-three-names">A</div>
            <div class="big-three-names">B</div>
            <div class="big-three-names">C</div>
            <div class="big-three-info one-sub">
                <div id="big-three-info-title">
                    A
                </div>
                <div id="big-three-info-description">
                    fdfdfsaf
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="big-three-info two-sub">
                <div id="big-three-info-title">
                    B
                </div>
                <div id="big-three-info-description">
                    fdfafa
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="big-three-info three-sub">
                <div id="big-three-info-title">
                    C
                </div>
                <div id="big-three-info-description">
                    fdsfsdfaf
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Besky : in the morning i had told you some thing ,,, remember ???? and you had said what exactly i mean ... this is what i meant...

Comment: go back to your previous question and try my answer

Comment: I tried your answer as well and it did the same thing.

Comment: oops !!! are you coming online with two profiles

Comment: `$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.big-three-names').click(function() {
    var i = $( this ).index();
    console.log(i)
    $('.big-three-info').css("display", "none")
    $('.big-three-info').eq(i).css("display", "block");
  });
  $('.big-three-info').eq(0).css("display", "block");
});`

Comment: you need to make some changes in the html also ,,,,, i think you must have done some mistake

Comment: My HTML is exactly like your answer yo yo. This should work for the other answer as well, because all you did was add the separate classes.

Comment: @Becky : see my answer becky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting `.index()` for `.html()` , remove `-1` from `.eq()` call

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('.big-three-names').click(function() {
         var i = $( this ).index();
         $('.big-three-info').css("display", "none")
         .eq(i).css("display", "block");
     });

     $('.big-three-info').eq(0).css("display", "block");
});
```

```css
.big-three-out {
 background-color: #CCC;
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto 0;
/* padding: 15px 0;*/
}
.big-three {
 margin: 75px 7.5% 25px 7.5%;
 height: 900px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
#big-three-title {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.6em;
 padding: 50px 0 30px 0;
}
#big-three-description {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.3em;
}
#big-three-names-out {
 width: 100%;
 height: 75px;
 margin: 50px 0;
}
.big-three-names {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 2px solid #FFF;
 width: 33.05%;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #000;
 color: #FFF;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.big-three-names:hover {
 background-color: blue;
 color: #FFF;
}
.big-three-info {
 margin: 50px 20%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 height: 550px;
  display: none; 
}
#big-three-info-title { 
 width: 100%;
 margin: 100px 0 25px 50px;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
#big-three-info-description { 
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: 50px;
 font-size: 1em;
}
.show{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="big-three-out">
    <div class="big-three">
        <div id="big-three-title">The Big three</div>
        <div id="big-three-description">Description.</div>
        <div id="big-three-names-out">
            <div class="big-three-names">A</div>
            <div class="big-three-names">B</div>
            <div class="big-three-names">C</div>
            <div class="big-three-info one-sub">
                <div id="big-three-info-title">
                    A
                </div>
                <div id="big-three-info-description">
                    fdfdfsaf
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="big-three-info two-sub">
                <div id="big-three-info-title">
                    B
                </div>
                <div id="big-three-info-description">
                    fdfafa
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="big-three-info three-sub">
                <div id="big-three-info-title">
                    C
                </div>
                <div id="big-three-info-description">
                    fdsfsdfaf
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this allow it to fadeIn? `$('.big-three-info').eq(i).css("display", "block").fadeIn(slow);`

Comment: @Becky No. Element is already visible when `.fadeIn()` called due to `.fadeIn()` being chained to `.css("display", "block")`; try removing `.css("display", "block")` before call to `.fadeIn()`

Answer (score 2):

In you're hide/show method, you're referencing the HTML of an element when all you need is the index.

Like so:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.big-three-names').click(function() {
    var i = $( this ).index();
    $('.big-three-info').fadeOut()  //.css("display", "none")
    $('.big-three-info').eq(i).fadeIn()  //.css("display", "block");
  });
  $('.big-three-info').eq(0).css("display", "block");
});
```

```css
.big-three-out {
 background-color: #CCC;
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto 0;
/* padding: 15px 0;*/
}
.big-three {
 margin: 75px 7.5% 25px 7.5%;
 height: 900px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
#big-three-title {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.6em;
 padding: 50px 0 30px 0;
}
#big-three-description {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.3em;
}
#big-three-names-out {
 width: 100%;
 height: 75px;
 margin: 50px 0;
}
.big-three-names {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 2px solid #FFF;
 width: 33.05%;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #000;
 color: #FFF;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.big-three-names:hover {
 background-color: blue;
 color: #FFF;
}
.big-three-info {
 margin: 50px 20%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 height: 550px;
  display: none; 
}
#big-three-info-title { 
 width: 100%;
 margin: 100px 0 25px 50px;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
#big-three-info-description { 
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: 50px;
 font-size: 1em;
}
.show{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="big-three-out">
    <div class="big-three">
        <div id="big-three-title">The Big three</div>
        <div id="big-three-description">Description.</div>
        <div id="big-three-names-out">
            <div class="big-three-names">A</div>
            <div class="big-three-names">B</div>
            <div class="big-three-names">C</div>
            <div class="big-three-info one-sub">
                <div id="big-three-info-title">
                    A
                </div>
                <div id="big-three-info-description">
                    fdfdfsaf
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="big-three-info two-sub">
                <div id="big-three-info-title">
                    B
                </div>
                <div id="big-three-info-description">
                    fdfafa
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="big-three-info three-sub">
                <div id="big-three-info-title">
                    C
                </div>
                <div id="big-three-info-description">
                    fdsfsdfaf
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/pwqbqyq9/2/)

checkout above working demo

```
$('.big-three-names').click(function() {


   $(".big-three-info").hide();
   $("."+$(this).attr("class").split(" ")[1]+"-sub").show();



    });


  $(document).ready(function(){

  $(".one-sub").show()


  })
```